# Can any settings reduce or eliminate the Mac OS X Lion Jumping Cursor Bug?

Tags: macos

How do you stop the jumping cursor bug in Mac OS X Lion?

I am using the Magic Mouse and the cursor keeps jumping to the edge of the screen very often, every minute or two I say. The mouse seems to take off in whatever direction the mouse is moving, just going way too far leaving the cursor at the edge of the screen

After googling, it looks like it is a widespread issue and definately a Mac OS X Lion bug.

Are there any solutions besides waiting for Apple to fix this? Afterall, could take ages and I need to get work done!... Can't downgrade to Snow Leopard, new laptop with Lion.

Comment: This is really prevalent on one of my 24" iMacs. I use the apple wireless keyboard and magic mouse and the cursor jumping happens only in Lion. If I boot back to 10.6 - it's fine. 10.7 seems to be not processing the mouse movements in a timely manner and what should be a small motion is detected as a large acceleration causing the pointer to hit an edge of the screen. I'm hoping someone figures out a workaround - it is _very_ disconcerting.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post mentions turning off mouse acceleration as a solution:

http://incredimike.com/blog/2011/08/os-x-lion-causing-a-jumpy-mouse-movement/

He supplies links to a command line script and an app that'll do it.  I haven't tried it as I'm hoping Apple fixes this before I feel like I need to muck with hidden settings.

Comment: Thanks for this. It does indeed work. But without the acceleration, the mouse becomes John Moschitta Jr. on 3 lbs. of espresso. Really unusable. A real shame. It's either live with the skips or live with the insane speed. Sigh. If it's one thing Apple has never done well (software or hardware), it's the mouse. Never understood that.